# How to get a response body while getting 403. Java

Tags: java, android, exception, httpurlconnection

I make a request to my web app, web app reports some errors.
nothing complicated. just like this:

```
{"password":["can't be blank"]}
```

and it returns it with code 403.

In my android app I use `HttpURLConnection` to make a request and I catch an exception white trying to `getInputStream`.

In that exception I can `getResponseMessage()`, but all I got is 'Forbidden'

How can I get an actual response body?

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0");
try {
    String result = IOUtils.toString(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    urlConnection.disconnect();
    App.SaveToken(result);
}catch(IOException exception){
    if (urlConnection.getResponseCode()==403)
    {
        return urlConnection.getResponseMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: `and it returns it with code 403.`. Hard to believe. Can you please show how a web app can return a 403?

Comment: It's my web app on my local server. And code is subject to change
    **render json: u.errors, :status=>403**

Comment: Yes it is your web app on your local server. Great. So you have access. Code subject to change. Ok. But what does it matter? You gave no answer to my question though. I repeat: how can your web app return a 403? Please show such code.

Comment: Ok thanks. Looks unfamiliar to me.  What kind of script language/server type is this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77955/discussion-between-ekiyanov-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the response code is not 200(or 2xx), use `getErrorStream()` instead of `getInputStream()`.